# Chrome CSS behaviour vs other popular browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm really struggling to reconcile a specific behaviour of Chrome, compared to latest versions of Firefox and Safari on Mac and IE on PC.

Comparison screenshot showing the issue in Chrome at the bottom:

https://screencast.com/t/Tj07m3Q0fX9

Only relevant CSS applied to this including the clipping path.

```
.top1 {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #6dcff6;
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 22px;
width: auto;
clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%);
}
```

When this site was launched everything was fine, which leads me to believe this may be a specific behaviour potentially introduced in an update. What is causing me an issue is all the code looks fine, it works well in most Mac browsers and IE on PC (not been able to test it on Chrome/Firefox on PC).

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Please post your code for helping you...

Comment: You are required to post a minimal example of the markup that causes the problem here. A link to your web site, which can change tomorrow, helps no one and will only get your question removed shortly. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: try removing this from `.top1` clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%);

Comment: Showing only your CSS still fails to follow the rules requiring an example of the problem and, since you changed your web site for the fix, this question no longer helps future visitors with the same issue and should be removed.

Comment: I disagree that it doesn't help anyone - Konstantinos's comments below are very helpful indeed when viewed in context to the screenshot and in particular the caniuse link. I always forget how carefully posters need to tread here in order to not fall foul of the rules and those who enjoy nothing more than policing them, and I'd suggest that even though this page as is seems to me to have value to others, you do whatever you feel comfortable doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On style.css:331 remove the following line

```
clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's perfect. Why is that interfering in Chrome and not others?

Comment: You may have a look at this: http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path. As far as I inspected your website, I could see that the only browser that actually recognized the property was Google Chrome. Glad I helped you out ! :)